# iPhone XCode UITabBarController and UINavigationController

Tags: iphone, ios, uinavigationcontroller

I'm trying to update my app to work on the iPhone 5 when I got the following error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'UIViewControllerHierarchyInconsistency',
reason: 'A view can only be associated with at most one view controller at a time!
View <UITableView: 0x88fbe00; frame = (0 20; 320 548); clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; 
autoresize = W+H; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x8395940>; layer = <CALayer: 0x8395350>;
contentOffset: {0, 0}> is associated with <UIViewController: 0x83967d0>. Clear this
association before associating this view with <UIViewController: 0x8381220>.'
```

I am running XCode version 4.5 and this has never happened before. I have tried to follow the steps in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/883510/loading-uinavigationcontroller-from-another-nib-automatically-by-uitabbarcontrol). This is what my MainWindow.xib looks like:

[image: MainWindow.xib]

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found the solution to mine.  Open the XIB file of the view that causes the exception when it should load.  Make sure there is not a ViewController object at the top of the Object list with the View beneath it.  If there is, move the View, which will move everything underneath it, out to the same level as the ViewController object.  Now delete the ViewController object and make sure your XIB class is set correctly to your ViewController class and hopefully it will work.

---

I have the same issue.  Xcode 4.5 built and run on iOS6 (device or simulator) I get this problem.  Xcode 4.5 running the app on < iOS6 is fine.  Exactly the same code built with Xcode < 4.5 AND running on iOS6 is fine.  So it appears to be an Xcode 4.5 and iOS6 combo.  I do not see what is causing it though.

Answer (score 0):

There is a table view in your hiearchy that is associated with two different view controllers through their `view` outlet. This is not a supported scenario, thus the exception. Take a look at your table views and see which one gets connected to multiple view controllers.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem for the last hour. After following all recommendations the problem persisted. When I deleted the derived data, the inconsistency exception finally went away. Lesson for the day, do delete derived data!!